# "Complex analysis," by Elias M. Stein: Answers.

Tags: complex-analysis

Does this book have answers to its problems in the back? I can't seem to view the back of the book properly on amazon preview.

Thanks.

Comment: Usually the preview includes the table of contents. If there is no entry in the table of contents listing "answers" or "Answers to selected exercises", my guess is there are no answers included.

Comment: If I am not mistaken there are some hints, but I think somebody has written answers to some of the questions

Comment: I just checked my copy, no there are no answers given to the problems and neither to the exercises (but some have hints). I wonder if there is a solution manual for this book?

Comment: Thanks guys - was hoping to use it for self study but would prefer a book with answers - does anyone have any other recommendations - ta

Comment: I confirm. I have the latest edition and it does not contain any solution to the exercises.

Comment: Lang's complex analysis. There is a solutions book for it, by sharkaki or whatever his name is

Comment: your welcome :p

Comment: Here link to Lang's complex analysis solution book http://www.amazon.com/Problems-Solutions-Complex-Analysis-Shakarchi/dp/0387988319/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_y

Comment: cheers - found them both on the UK site

Answer (score 2):

None of the four books in his "Princeton Lectures in Analysis" series have solutions but on occasion there are hints after a problem is stated.